# creating symbolic link: Protocol error

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, file-permissions, symlink

I have created linux (Centos) on my virtual box. When I ssh to it and I try to create symbolic link (on my shared folder with full access):

```
ln -s path/folder/example myFolder
```

I get error:

```
ln: creating symbolic link `myFolder': Protocol error
```

Is there any reason or solution to this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am also seeing similar issue `root@57856515e02b:/artifacts/test/install/lib# ln -s /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.5 /artifacts/test/install/lib/
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/artifacts/test/install/lib/tcl8.5': Protocol error`

Comment: For me, running as admin wasn't enough, but here was my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60741351/470749

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a problem with the host filesystem. Check the permissions on the host folder are adequate and the the host filesystem supports symlinks.

Comment: The host system is windows 7. Is there any solution to enable it?

Comment: Bad solution for this is to create symlinks in windows 7 by using mklink. Example: mklink /D myFolder path/folder/example

Comment: from which API/layer does the `Protocol error` message come from here?

Comment: whatever app you used to launch your VM, VBox, or vagrant or ... you have to run the app _as an administrator_

Answer (score 35):

Right click on your command prompt and "Run as Administrator" (or whatever program you're using to make those symlinks needs to be run as adminstrator).

Comment: Actually, protocol errors in creating symlinks are common to virtual boxes running on windows. Running the shell as an admin generally corrects the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue but when you run the VM as administrator you'll be able to create symbolic links. For more information also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28674584/1494559

Comment: Can you explain what you need to do to "Right click"?  Is that a particular escape sequence in the SSH session?

Comment: @TobySpeight they mean right-click the icon/shortcut/whatever in Windows that launches the command prompt.

Comment: @alexw, what does Windows have to do with any of this?

Comment: OP says that their host OS is windows 7.

Comment: This should have been the accepted solution.  However the host is launching the VM, it has to done as _an administrator_

Comment: Im having this problem in windows 10, running the cmd as admin tried halting and much more

Answer (score 30):

Here is the solution in a ticket on virtualbox.org :
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085#comment:32
(Note: Execute "whoami /priv" in console with Administrative privileges)

> I have done some Windows research on this bug.
>
> If your user is of the Administrator type (rather than a Standard
>   account), there's no way to run VB with symlinks working without the
>   UAC prompt.
>
> If you have a Standard user account (or if you are willing to switch
>   your account to Standard and create a separate Admin account), the
>   solution exists. You will, however, need admin privileges to
>   accomplish several of the steps (not necesarrily for your user
>   account).
>
> 1. Run the Local Security Policy (Win+R, type "secpol.msc", confirm UAC). Then navigate to "Local Policies->User Rights Assignment".
> 2. Find the permission called "Create symbolic links" and double-click it. Add your user to the list of objects having this
>      permission. Or you can add the "Users" group. Log off and log on. You
>      can check the success by running in console:
>
>    ```
>    whoami /priv
>    ```
>
>    If you see the privilege SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege enabled, you've
>      done well.
> 3. Make sure your user has proper access to the shared folder on host system.
> 4. As mentioned here earlier, execute
>
>    ```
>    VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
>    ```
>
>    in a console from the C:\Program Files\VirtualBox folder. Don't forget
>      to substitute VM_NAME with the name of your VM and SHARE_NAME with the
>      name of the shared folder (as it appears in the VM settings).
> 5. You're done.
>
> If you happen to own one of the "lesser" version of windows (e.g. 7
>   Home), you don't have the "secpol.msc" utility. See 
>   [How do I grant SeCreateSymbolicLink on Windows Vista Home edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815472/how-do-i-grant-secreatesymboliclink-on-windows-vista-home-edition)
>   for help.

Comment: Thanks, use secpol.msc and gave myself privs. Worked perfectly.

Comment: It works, thanks! Small note though: if whoami /priv lists your privilege as "Disabled" - don't worry, it just means something else (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e24a35b3-fb72-4918-8e51-562e2ad8d8f5/what-is-the-state-column-returned-by-whoami-priv?forum=winserversecurity) . If it is listed, it works for your user.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to solve my symlinking problem in the Drupal VM.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, Windows VirtualBox hosts doesn't support links (from https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)

> Starting with version 4.0, VirtualBox shared folders also support
>   symbolic links (symlinks), under the following conditions:
>
> The host operating system must support symlinks (i.e. a Mac, Linux or
>   Solaris host is required).
>
> Currently only Linux and Solaris Guest Additions support symlinks.
>
> For security reasons the guest OS is not allowed to create symlinks by
>   default. If you trust the guest OS to not abuse the functionality, you
>   can enable creation of symlinks for "sharename" with:
>
> VBoxManage setextradata "VM name"
>   VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/sharename 1

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by changing the **local security policy** in my windows. Search for **local security policy** and open it then on the left-hand side select **Local Policies -> User Rights Assignments -> Create Symbolic Links**

- Click on Add User or Group
- Type in **everyone** in the select user/group prompt.
- Reboot your system

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

**By default VirtualBox VM disables creation of symbolic links.**

Oracle VM VirtualBox shared folders support symbolic links under the following conditions:

- *The host operating system must support symlinks. For example, a Mac OS X, Linux, or Oracle Solaris host is required.*
- *Currently only Linux and Oracle Solaris Guest Additions support symlinks.*
- *For security reasons the guest OS is not allowed to create symlinks by default.*

**To enable creation of symlinks for a shared folder you should do:**

1. Run this command on your host (where {VM_name} is the name of VM and {share_folder_name} is the name of shared directory):

```sh
$ VBoxManage setextradata "{VM_name}" VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/{share_folder_name} 1
```

In my case it looks like:

```sh
$ VBoxManage setextradata "ubuntu16" VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/shared 1
```

2. Reboot the VM.

**More information you can find here:**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/E97727/html/sharedfolders.html
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18572?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2

Answer (score 0):

find the cmd.exe file.
Right click on the cmd.exe .
Select "Run as Administrator" menu option.
It should work perfectly.

Comment: You seem confused; why would you expect a CentOS box to have a `cmd.exe`, and how do you expect "Right click" to be performed in an SSH session?

Comment: This answer is referring to the host OS. You missed the part where OP stated they are on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to again tell VirtualBox to enable symlinks. Here's the complete solution

Have this in your vagrant file,

```yaml
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/Folder_Name", "1"]
end
```

I recommended comment out any sync folder and let default ./(at host) synced at /vagrant(at guest). This will make sure your **shared folder(Folder_Name)** name is always **vagrant** as mentioned here https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/. Also, you won't face issues with ssh

If the symlink protocol error returns after restart or still persists run

```yaml
VBoxManage setextradata "VM_Name" VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/Folder_Name 1

vagrant halt
vagrant up

vagrant ssh
```

Usually, VBoxManagee is located at C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\

Verify working of symlink by going to /vagrant and running

```yaml
touch test.txt && ln -s test.txt test1.txt
```

PS: I have tried this on Windows Home which has limited accessibility to security settings

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same error in virtual box ( Lubuntu running in Windows 10). Issue got resolved by running "Oracle VM Virtualbox" using 'Run As Administrator' option.