# Capistrano Deploy. creating symbolic link : protocol error

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano, web-deployment, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy locally with Capistrano V3 a sample project. If i run the git:check:

```
$ cap staging git:check
```

I've got success! But when I run:

```
$ cap staging deploy
```

I got the error:

```
DEBUG[038bd0e3] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/myapp/releases/20141011155415 /var/www/myapp/current
DEBUG[038bd0e3]         ln:
DEBUG[038bd0e3]         creating symbolic link `/var/www/myapp/current'
DEBUG[038bd0e3]         : Protocol error
DEBUG[038bd0e3]
```

It seems that the command cannot create the symlink. I tried to run it manually, and I've the same error.

Here is my **deploy.rb**

```
set :application, 'myapp'
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:myuser/repo.git" #Just change to not expose informations...
set :branch, "master"

set :deploy_to, '/var/www/myapp'
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :use_sudo, false
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :user, "deploy"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you confirmed **the same error** occurs when you try to do it manually, the issue is NOT with Capistrano.  It is a problem on the host machine.

[Elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895256/creating-symbolic-link-protocol-error) this same question was answered.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, I think my issue and the question you mentioned are not exactly the same situation. The source path and the symbol link are in the very OS, although I'm using Vagrant.