# Run vagrant VM with different user

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, user-permissions

*I know this question overlaps with some other [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) sites, however since I want a development environment this matches for StackOverflow.*

I'm setting up an VM with vagrant to extend a Linux service on a windows host. It works fine so far just softlinks don't work on shared folders. This is a known bug of [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085). There is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/815557/995926) if you run virtual box on an account without admin permissions. However this is no option for me. AFIK I can modify the group permissions of a standard user so that they can create a symlink (on NTFS), but this [does not work for admin users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15330511/995926). So I need to run the VM with a different user account. **Any idea how I can setup vagrant to run a VM with a different user?**

Comment: At first I though you were trying to run as a different user on the guest, but it seems you're trying to run VBox and the Vagrant process on your Windows host using a non-admin account? If so, have you tried runas.exe?

Comment: I would like to but vagrant is executing the headless virtual box vm. I have no idea how to inject a runas in vagrant.

Comment: @Yser no I need to run the virtualbox.exe with a different user.